# Vue template compilation failed while parsing file

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, компоненты

Все из-за того что к главному скрипту я подключаю сразу несколько компонентов. 
К примеру:

> import Sidebar from '../sidebar.vue'
>
> import Widget from'../widget.vue'

То есть в  любом случае не получается подключить много компонентов

```js
import Vue from '../node_modules/vue/dist/vue.js'
import login from '../components/login.vue'
import settings from '../components/settings.vue'

Vue.component('login', login)

new Vue({
 el: '#app',
 data: {
  user: {
          mail : '',
          password : '',
          name : '',
        }
 },
 components: {
  'login': login
 }

})
```

```js
/* LOGIN COMPONENT */

<template>
 <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-7 left_content">
  <h3>Meet your love<br>Where you did<br>not expect</h3>
  <form id="form" action="settings.html" v-on:submit="validateForm">
   <input type="text" v-model="user.mail"
   v-bind:class="{ 'is-invalid': attemptSubmit && missingMail }"
    
    placeholder="Email" name="">
   <input type="text" v-model="user.password" 
   v-bind:class="{ 'is-invalid': attemptSubmit && missingPassword }" placeholder="Password"  name="">
   
   <a href="register_page.html" class="register_btn ">Don't have an account yet?</a>
   <input type="submit" class="submit_btn" value="Sign in">

   <div class="form_link">
    <a href="#">Terms</a>
    <a href="#">Privacy Policy & Safety</a>
   </div>
  </form>
 </div>
</template>
<script >
 module.exports = {
  data: function(){
  return{
   user: {
            mail : '',
            password : '',
            name : '', 
         },
    hello: '',
     attemptSubmit: false
   }

  },
  computed: {
   missingMail: function () { 
    if(this.user.mail != "test" || this.user.mail == "test"){
     this.attemptSubmit = true;
     return true; 
    }
   },
      missingPassword: function () {
       if(this.user.password != "test" || this.user.password == ""){
          return true;
       }
      }
  },
  methods: {
   
        validateForm: function (event) {
    if (this.user.mail == "test" && this.user.password == "test") {
     alert('Success');
        this.attemptSubmit = true;
        
    }else if ( this.missingMail || this.missingPassword){
     event.preventDefault();
     alert('Fill in form');
    }else if (this.user.mail != "test" || this.user.password != "test") {
     alert('E-mail or password are incorrect');
     event.preventDefault();

    }
      }

  },
 }

</script>
```

```js
/* SETTINGS COMPONENT */
<template>

 <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-5 col-sm-5 settings_block">
  
  <div class="settings_title">
   <h4>Settings</h4>
   <img src="img/member4.jpg">
  </div> 
  <div class="user_info">
   <div class="user_avatar">
    <img src="img/section_bg.jpg">
    <div class="online_circle"></div>
   </div>
   <h4>John Larckin</h4>
   <a href="#">
    <img src="img/cam.svg" class="svg">
   </a>
  </div>
  <div class="tag_toggler">
   <div class="icon">
    <img src="img/options.svg" class="svg">
   </div>
   <h4>Select tag</h4>
   <div class="checkbox_block">
    <label class="switch">
      <input type="checkbox">
      <span class="slider round"></span>
    </label>
   </div> 
  </div>
  <div class="description">
   <p> Something about you </p>
   <p> John Larckin </p>
  </div>
  <div class="content_toggler">
   <div class="content_toggler_item">
    <a href="chat.html">
     <img src="img/chat.svg" class="svg">
    </a>
   </div>
   <div class="content_toggler_item">
    <a href="map.html">
     <img src="img/layers.svg" class="svg">
    </a>
   </div>
   <div class="content_toggler_item active">
    <a href="settings.html">
     <img src="img/social.svg" class="svg">
    </a>
   </div>
  </div> 
 </div>
 <div class="add_room_btn">
  <a href="create_room.html">
   <img src="img/signs.svg" class="svg">
  </a>
 </div>
 <div class="google_map" id="map"></div>

</template>
<script>
 
</script>
```

**Полный текст ошибки:
 Vue template compilation failed while parsing file: D:\vizumia_messenger\components\settings.vue
    at compileTemplate (D:\vizumia_messenger\node_modules\vueify\lib\template-compiler.js:11:11)
    at D:\vizumia_messenger\node_modules\vueify\lib\compiler.js:243:24
    at 
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)**

Comment: приведите полный текст ошибки

Comment: Сейчас, спасибо.

Comment: Можете посмотреть, пожалуйста?